# VLC ProcessStartInfo Parameters to keep VLC always On top

Tags: vb.net, vlc

I need to open VLC via a button click in VB.net program. I further require to set the VLC always on top setting to yes. The code to start VLC works as below:

```
 Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
                startInfo.FileName = ProgPath
                startInfo.Arguments = FilePath
                Process.Start(startInfo)
```

Is there a way to add further parametrs to set the always on top setting in VLC? I looked for the setting in their command line help file and found this but have no idea how to implement it.

```
--video-on-top, --no-video-on-top
                             Always on top (default disabled)
      Always place the video window on top of other windows. (default
      disabled)
```

is it possible to include that in my code to play the file and keep the VLC window on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just concatenate it together with the `FilePath` variable. Remember to put quotes around file paths as they may contain spaces.

```
startInfo.Arguments = """" & FilePath & """ --video-on-top --no-video-on-top"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly  `startInfo.Arguments = """" & FilePath & """ --video-on-top"` Thank you. I was trying all sorts of dividers. The penny didn't drop that the '--' was the divider between the parm. and the file path. LOL a blond moment! I did search but found no examples of the code as to how to implement the parms. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer. You should have written this as a comment instead. And the `--` is not the divider, the spaces are _**(note the space between `"""` and `--video-on-top`)**_. Windows passes parameters like this: `application.exe "param1" "param2" "param3"`. The `--` is just what VLC uses to begin parameters. It could be anything `+`, `|||` `#`, `%`, `-`. It just depends on how the target application defines it.

Comment: With your code the application will be opened for example like this: `vlc.exe "C:\Videos\hello world.wma" --video-on-top` **<- note the space**. A few command line examples at: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments